# Is it permissible for a Muslim to rent a venue for a wedding, where the venue has a liquor license?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, wedding

Is it permissible for a Muslim to rent a venue for a wedding, where the venue has a liquor license?  Such as the venue organising to remove any form of alcohol from the venue to host the slim wedding.

Answer (score 3):

As far as as I understood your Question. I can't see where the problem is.
 If the Muslims who want to organize or get married just, let the owner -I suppose he is non-Muslim and you are in a non-Muslim country- of the venue know that they don't want any kind of alcohol being served during the wedding and he accepted everything is fine.

Neither does the owner need to (totally) remove any form of alcohol form his venue nor do the Muslims need to feel bad because this venue usually sells alcohol, as they are not involved in this and they can't be responsible for what others do unless the owner is Muslim in that case they should at least advice him and avoid the place, as long as he didn't repent from this sinful act according to [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/84). See for example [6:164](http://legacy.quran.com/6/164), [74:38](http://legacy.quran.com/74/38).

**But** if you can find a location for the wedding where there's no alcohol served, which is large enough you should avoid any other possibility! (see also [this fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=35180) in Arabic, which discourage from celebrating a wedding in a place where alcohol is served)

And Allah knows best!