# Is it okay if I eat at a halal restaurant that serves beer/alcohol?

Tags: fiqh, food, alcohol

I have an exchange program at Madrid, Spain for 5 months.

There is a lot of restaurant here that show Halal at their restaurant name, for an example Palmira & La Libanesa (at Gran Via,Madrid).

When I get into the restaurant, I saw there is alcohol served in the menu.

For confirmation I ask them , "Is it Halal?" , they said "Yes, it is Halal!"

and I ask them why you served cerveza/beer here, they said it is common in here.

So my question is it okay for me to eat there, or should i look for other restaurant or just make my own meal (cook)?

[Palmira Restaurant](https://www.google.es/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0xd42287c7cb8db63:0x3a5eafe4799e06a7!2m10!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i20!16m4!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!3m1!7e115!4shttps://picasaweb.google.com/lh/sredir?uname%3D118040386876385169878%26id%3D6331286688530317858%26target%3DPHOTO!5s%20-%20Google%20Search&imagekey=!1e3!2s-xVdCqqba57k/V90_stkCQiI/AAAAAAAAAFU/4b6PsVLVmV45CCouBTjOCWSfy0DnjMHLACLIB)

[La Libanesa Restaurant](https://www.google.es/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0xd42287c7eebca5b%3A0xc2a22e646af7c2f6!2m10!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i20!16m4!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!3m1!7e115!4shttps%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Flh%2Fsredir%3Funame%3D103944206875108813232%26id%3D6076008881930710914%26target%3DPHOTO!5s%20-%20Google%20Search&imagekey=!1e3!2s-ic8ZOYWnFzQ%2FVNUMm0sIm_I%2FAAAAAAAAAEM%2F8rTBJXAPdfMsmnnZGPvegoAyemRWvt-vg)

Comment: "Is it ok?" is somewhat wide or flexible. Drinking alcohol is haram by Quran, selling, and about any act helping a possible consummation etc. is haram by sunnah. Yes for you if you don't do so it might be "ok" to go there. But a better choice would be going somewhere where no alcohol is served!

Comment: Ask yourself this, would it be halal to eat at a restaurant that's not run by muslims and serves alcohol? If that is halal, then eating at those you have in mind will be as well.

Comment: Only dining with people who have alcoholic beverages is forbidden as per hadith. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever believes in Allaah and the Last Day, let him not sit at a table where wine is being drunk.” Narrated by Ahmad, 126; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Irwa’ al-Ghaleel, 7/6.

Comment: According to the hadith above from Abu AbdulQayyum you're allowed to do so as long as you're not sitting with someone who drinks alcohol.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a restaurant that serves or offers alcohol by itself is not "halal":

- > The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Allah has cursed wine, its drinker, **its server**, **its seller**, its buyer, its presser, the one for whom it is pressed, **the one who conveys it**, and **the one to whom it is conveyed**.  ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/6))
- > "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed **ten** involved in wine: The one who presses it, the one who has it pressed, its drinker, **its carrier**, and the **one it is carried to**, **its server**, **its seller**, **the consumption of its price**, the one who purchases it and the one it was purchased for." ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/14/97))

as the income is haram, and everything surrounding it and its consummation is haram. Not only drinking it which is haram by the Qur'an, see also the chronology of the prohibition in  [Was alcohol permitted long ago, before Mohammad was born?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28313/was-alcohol-permitted-long-ago-before-mohammad-was-born).

So by choosing to eat at such a restaurant you -at least morally- help the owner to go forth selling and delivering alcohol and if he was a Muslim you may by this somehow confirming his misdeed and sin.

Most if not all scholars would say if there's a really halal restaurant it is better to go there, if not you may consider cooking for yourself or at least advise your Muslim brother and tell him about the sin he is committing.

See also [Is it permissible for a Muslim to rent a venue for a wedding, where the venue has a liquor license?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33484/is-it-permissible-for-a-muslim-to-rent-a-venue-for-a-wedding-where-the-venue-ha/33510?s=1|28.8151#33510)